# Make augment object stationary in ARCore Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I am trying to augment an object using ARCore. After agumentation I need to make the object as stationary. But when I move my device or change it's position then the augmented object also moved. I need to stop it's movement. How to resolve the issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to add a renderable and have to anchored so it stays in the same position when you move the device/camera, then using regular anchor nodes should achieve this.

For example the following code will anchor a node relative to the centre of the camera preview:

```js
          //Add an Anchor and a renderable in front of the camera       
          Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
          float[] pos = { 0,0,-1 };
          float[] rotation = {0,0,0,1};
          Anchor anchor =  session.createAnchor(new Pose(pos, rotation));
          anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
          anchorNode.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
          anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
```

Note - it may be that you are seeing you renderable move sometimes even when using anchor nodes? I have seen this also occasionally in the past with different apps so it may be simply a glitch with certain versions of ARCore even when using anchor nodes as intended.

Comment: Sorry, I tried the above code. but still it shows the same result.

Comment: @Codemaker Can you share a screen shot or view of what you are seeing, or if not describe it in bit more detail?